# Trouble with incompatible layers CNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm attempting to fit() my CNN model and I am having issues with layers working together.

```
from keras.engine import input_layer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense , Activation , Dropout ,Flatten, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D

# The model is as follows...

face_model = Sequential()
input_shape_face = (48, 48, 1)
face_model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size= (3, 3), input_shape = input_shape_face, padding= 'same', activation = 'LeakyReLU'))
face_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), padding= 'same'))
face_model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size= (3, 3), padding= 'same', activation = 'LeakyReLU'))
face_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), padding= 'same'))
face_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size= (3, 3), padding= 'same', activation = 'LeakyReLU'))
face_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2),  padding= 'same'))
face_model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size= (3, 3), padding= 'same', activation = 'LeakyReLU'))
face_model.add(Flatten())
face_model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'LeakyReLU'))
face_model.add(Dense(6, activation = 'softmax'))


face_model.summary()
```

Summary of my layers:

```
Model: "sequential_34"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_92 (Conv2D)          (None, 48, 48, 8)         80        
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_69 (MaxPoolin  (None, 24, 24, 8)        0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_93 (Conv2D)          (None, 24, 24, 16)        1168      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_70 (MaxPoolin  (None, 12, 12, 16)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_94 (Conv2D)          (None, 12, 12, 32)        4640      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_71 (MaxPoolin  (None, 6, 6, 32)         0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_95 (Conv2D)          (None, 6, 6, 64)          18496     
                                                                 
 flatten_8 (Flatten)         (None, 2304)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_57 (Dense)            (None, 128)               295040    
                                                                 
 dense_58 (Dense)            (None, 6)                 774       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 320,198
Trainable params: 320,198
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

```
# Compiling the model

face_model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= 'adam', metrics= ['accuracy'])

face_model.fit(facial_training_set, batch_size= batch_size, epochs= epochs, verbose= 1, validation_data= facial_testing_set)
```

The error I am recieving:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 280, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_34' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense_57" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2304, but received input with shape (48, 384)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_34' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(48, 48, 1), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
face_model = Sequential()
input_shape_face = (48, 48, 1)
face_model.add(input_layer.Input(shape=input_shape_face))
face_model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='LeakyReLU'))
face_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
face_model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='LeakyReLU'))
face_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
face_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='LeakyReLU'))
face_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
face_model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='LeakyReLU'))
face_model.add(Flatten())
face_model.add(Dense(128, activation='LeakyReLU'))
face_model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))

face_model.summary()
```

Try this if it works! I guess the input shape is not compatible.

Comment: It still gives me an error on the Flatten() > Dense() layers

Comment: `    Input 0 of layer "dense_59" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2304, but received input with shape (48, 384)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_35' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(48, 48, 1), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None `

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried reshaping the input data?

`facial_training_set = np.array(facial_training_set).reshape((-1, 48, 48, 1))`
`facial_testing_set = np.array(facial_testing_set).reshape((-1, 48, 48, 1))`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For conv2D the input shape should be like this:
input_shape = (4, 28, 28, 3)